# Not able to use firebase storage and firestore properly

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

[Fire Storage][No image type][Firestore][looks good]I was trying to build a galley app and store data in firestore and storage. Then using it to display it like a normal gallery, when you click on it. In my google storage, I can see a folder with the name null(I don't understand why) and inside it images. Inside it should be images but their are images but not of type image. Could you see why am I getting null folder and no image type in my storage.
'''

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageRetrieve extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? userId;
  const ImageRetrieve({Key? key, this.userId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImageRetrieve> createState() => _ImageRetrieveState();
}

class _ImageRetrieveState extends State<ImageRetrieve> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Your Images")),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(widget.userId)
            .collection("images")
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data.docs.length != 0) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  String url = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['downloadURL'];
                  return Image.network(
                    url,
                    height: 300,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Text("No images found"),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return (const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class ImageUpload extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? userId;
  const ImageUpload({Key? key, this.userId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImageUpload> createState() => _ImageUploadState();
}

class _ImageUploadState extends State<ImageUpload> {
  // initializing some values
  File? _image;
  final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  String? downloadURL;

  // picking the image

  Future imagePickerMethod() async {
    final pick = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if (pick != null) {
        _image = File(pick.path);
      } else {
        showSnackBar("No File selected", Duration(milliseconds: 400));
      }
    });
  }

  // uploading the image to firebase cloudstore
  Future uploadImage(File _image) async {
    final imgId = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('${widget.userId}/images')
        .child("post_$imgId");

    await reference.putFile(_image);
    downloadURL = await reference.getDownloadURL();

    // cloud firestore
    await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(widget.userId)
        .collection("images")
        .add({'downloadURL': downloadURL}).whenComplete(
            () => showSnackBar("Image Uploaded", Duration(seconds: 2)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Upload Image "),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                child: SizedBox(
                    height: 500,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      const Text("Upload Image"),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 300,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.green),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                // the image that we wanted to upload
                                Expanded(
                                    child: _image == null
                                        ? const Center(
                                        child: Text("No image selected"))
                                        : Image.file(_image!)),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      imagePickerMethod();
                                    },
                                    child: const Text("Select Image")),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (_image != null) {
                                        uploadImage(_image!);
                                      } else {
                                        showSnackBar("Select Image first",
                                            Duration(milliseconds: 400));
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: const Text("Upload Image")),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ])))),
      ),
    );
  }

  // show snack bar

  showSnackBar(String snackText, Duration d) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(snackText), duration: d);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)